# Is it possible to map jooq Record from string

Tags: java, postgresql, jooq

I have a case where I need to map jooq Record from json to class instance. We have used our own mapper for this in the past, but underlying table had only basic types so it was working fine. Now we have a need to map Postgres `interval` type to jooq `YearToSecond` and it is not working anymore.

I was wondering if there is a way to create these via jooq api or at least somehow get to the underlying mapper that jooq uses (I assume jooq has some kind of a mapper underneath).

Example:
`{"my_text":"This is text","my_interval_type":"05:00:00"}` to deserialize to `MyRecord` class which will have `String myText` and `YearToSecond myIntervalType` fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic way to map JSON strings to jOOQ `Result` values is by using [`DSLContext.fetchFromJSON(String)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/DSLContext.html#fetchFromJSON(java.lang.String)).

Unfortunately, as of jOOQ 3.16, you cannot yet provide data type information to this mechanism, so everything will be a `String`, there's no implied `YearToSecond` support. There's a pending feature request https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/12012, which should ship soon as it is indeed very useful.

That feature request is merely a matter of opening up jOOQ's internals, which you already correctly assumed, existed. The relevant class in jOOQ 3.16 is `org.jooq.impl.JSONReader`, which could do the trick for you as a workaround, if you're willing to access jOOQ's internals via reflection?

Comment: Thanks, if you remember this question once it is added to version, please update your response. If not, maybe I will add another response which will call this new functionality.

Comment: @DamirCiganović-Janković: *"Narrator: He didn't remember any specific answer among his 3000 answers"*. But you can ping me and I will. Or, I might stumble upon this in many years, and I might.

Comment: Damn, narrator is never wrong :-) Deal, I will ping you